# why am i only getting Nosuchelement - Selenium headless error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

OKay, I've got this problem with using xpath and headless in chromedriver. it works when i run it with non-headless but gives

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="discussion-list-5f9f8b4c804455f9f8b4c722e121"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/div/a"}
```

i have

```
time.sleep(30)

ca = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="discussion-list-5f9f8b4c804455f9f8b4c722e121"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/div/a').get_attribute('title')
print(ca)`
```

I saw everyone saying to add in

```
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1080x720")
```

but that's not working. :-/

Comment: Can you try to store a screenshot from headless mode and see if the element is actually loading/

Comment: yes it is loading, both elements and the discussion list section

Comment: Can you try the wait methods described in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7964299